# the proper way to wire up multiple supply rails

Tags: power, resistors, voltage-regulator

I am making a hexcopter for a shool project that is going to be powered and controlled via an arduino project.
my current setup is as follows:
[image]
Where the linear regulators are the 6 speed controllers' 5v outputs, normally for radios and not motors, that I'm using to power the arduino, and c1 is a brown out capacitor.
**My Problem: **The regulators are slightly different voltages, and the highest output will feed into the lower outputs, which is terrible for the regulators.
I've came up with a solution:

[image]

the theory of operation is that if a regulator is (at most) 0.05V off, instead of forcing the linear regulator down to said voltage, this puts a 20 ohm resistance between the two, allowing for (at most) 2.5mA of backwards current. This will also smooth out the load between the regulators, while not impeding any load under 3 amps..

thoughts?

sugestions?

Comment: This is the "BEC" output of the speed controllers? What current is it capable of? How much current do you require? *Are* they really linear regulators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than parallel all the regulators just split the loads into separate circuits with a common ground. Use one regulator to power the logic, another for one or two motors, etc., another for the camera.

With this arrangement you would:

- solve the problem you have correctly identified
- limit the maximum fault current to that of one regulator
- simplify debugging

Comment: sadly, this isn't possible. the Electronic speed controllers provide 3 phase AC for brushless motors on the side, the regulators pictured are simply the outputs that are supposed to be for a radio, as provided by a pwm cable

Comment: You need to improve the original question then. It's not clear what the problem is. "_Where the linear regulators are the 6 speed controllers that I'm using to power the arduino._" Speed controllers don't power Arduinos. "_The regulators pictured are simply the outputs that are supposed to be for a radio._" Regulators as outputs? For a radio? This is non-nonsensical.

Comment: the problem is very clear, and it's even formatted: "**My Problem: **The regulators are slightly different voltages, and the highest output will feed into the lower outputs, which is terrible for the regulators"

Comment: @tuskiomi But you have not sufficiently explained why you need to parallel the regulators. Why can't you use a single larger regulator? Or, for motors, don't use a regulator at all, because the ESCs and motors are likely tolerant of a range of input voltages.

Comment: @unit128_t fixed.

Comment: @tuskiomi: "_The problem is very clear_" to you because you can see the equipment. You have to put yourself in the position of the reader who only has the words you put down. "I wish to power the Arduino from the auxiliary 5 V outputs of six quadcoptor motor speed controllers", might have got the idea across a little better. The Arduino has an on-board regulator. Can you not feed it directly from the battery?

Comment: @transistor sadly, not. the battery is charged to a nominal 14V, while the arduino is only specced to 12V. let me see If I can fix this.